# Create shadow root/dom in firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, shadow-dom

I am building Javascript widget that embeded's form on website. I am encapsulating my widget by putting it in shadow dom. It works fine in Chrome but in firefox it does not work at all.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. Can you share a demo of the code you have here? ShadowDOM is not completely supported in Firefox yet.

Comment: It is not suppported at all in Firefox. webkitCreateShadowRoot is deprecated in favor of attachShadow which is not implemented yet in firefox. The only way I can encapsulate widget's CSS from rest  of the page is through Iframe. I can't share code it is on my comp and it is big.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [webcomponents.js](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs) library in order to polyfill the [Shadow DOM features](http://webcomponents.org/polyfills/shadow-dom/) in Firefox, IE and Edge.